# NodeJS, Merge two pdfs

Tags: node.js, pdf, merge, node-pdfkit

Hy, i have two .pdf and i want to merge them using node, i already tried using Ghostscript, and exec from node , but GhostScript is a bit buggy, and sometimes it gives segmentation fault level 11, which i already researched and its a common bug.

```
Processing pages 1 through 2.
Page 1
Page 2
Segmentation fault: 11
```

So my question is if there is a module that can do the merge of two PDF for me, already tried PDFMake , and PDFKit, but i cant seem to find any option to merge files.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

A module named [pdf-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-merge) worked great for me. It requires a program called PDFtk. Make sure you install the [server version of PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/).